# Does AnyOne knows how to reverse python file that is encoded into elf binary .cpython-310.so extension? Please Help me Out

Tags: c, elf, python, binary, disassemblers

Following is the link to the file that I want to reverse. This is the **python** file that is encoded in **cpython** or **cython** and it is now a binary file.

Please help me to decode it as it is very important for me.

[File](https://anonfiles.com/cf08WfU6y1/extractor.cpython-311_so)

Comment: Which link? Can you mention what you have tried and failed?

Comment: https://anonfiles.com/z3S0i2V0y5/extractor.cpython-311_so

Comment: @JameelSafdar - It's always best to edit your question with more information rather than answering it in the comment section.  I have done the file link.